# How can I display the quick access toolbar icons in colour in office 2016?

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-2016

Currently, all my MS Office 2016 quick access toolbar icons are monochromatic, now I barely can see a image at all and are impossible to decipher. The other possibilty is use the white theme, but is too bright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for customizing the QAT.

Read more about the UI and its possible customizations in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

The Backstage UI is described in depth in the following articles:

- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)